# How can I pass the item String that I selected from ListView to another fragment?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to pass the data (a string that I select) from one fragment from a listview to another fragment in an edittext. How is this possible in this case?

Can I use bundle? If yes, how?

First fragment:

```
public class AirportPostFragment extends Fragment {

String stringsList[];
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ListView listViewAirports;
private EditText editSearch;
Context myContext;
XmlPullParser parser;
HashSet airport_list;
HashSet<String> list = new HashSet<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_airportpost, container, false);

    listViewAirports = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_airports);
    editSearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_airport);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringsList);

    listViewAirports.setAdapter(adapter);
    listViewAirports.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new FinishPostFragment()).commit();
        }
    });

    searchAirport();
    return rootView;
}
```

SecondFragment:

```
public class FinishPostFragment extends Fragment{

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finishpost, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.finish_post_button, menu);
}
}
```

Comment: There are few problems here ... every one is well documented over internet (and bazillion similar questions here on SO) ... 1. to get selected item use `AdapterView.getItemAtPosition` 2. yes, you can use `Bundle` with `Fragment.set/getArguments`

Answer (score 1):

you should use `Bundle` 
here is an example

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = new FinishPostFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("data", "your string");
fragment.setArgument(bundle);
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
```

and in your second fragment:

```
String data = getArguments().getString("data");
```

and there is a cleaner way for that. in your second fragment, add a `newInstance` function :

```
public static final String DATA_TAG="data";
private String mData;
public static FinishPostFragment newInstance(String data) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(DATA_TAG, data);
        FinishPostFragment fragment = new FinishPostFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
}

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null)
            mData = getArguments().getString(DATA_TAG);
        }
    }
```